# Rewrite URL for hyphens on URL

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I am trying to enable mod_write's rewrite URL and am not able to get it to work for hyphens in the URL format. Could you please assist me on this.

`www.domain.com/username/Lord-Voldermort`

redirect to

`www.domain.com/user.php?username=Lord Voldermort`

Comment: What if the user name does actually contain a hyphen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

RewriteRule ^username/([a-z0-9\-]+)$ /user.php?username=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

Comment: That question just had an example. What would the regular expression be for the rule to support hypens? I am currently using this.

`RewriteRule ^username/([a-z0-9]+)$ /user.php?username=$1 [QSA,NC,L]`

Dont seem to be able to get the above to work for hypens

Answer (score 1):

I would use two rules for that. 1st rewrite /username/xxx to user.php?username=xxx, then replace every '-' to ' ':

```
RewriteRule ^username/(.*)$ /user.php?username=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^user\.php\?username=
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)\-(.*) $1\ $2 [N]
```

**EDIT** This is not working propery, you have to switch the order of both tasks. Anyway netadictos has answered your question.